# Outputing array from php in javascript console

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a simple ajax script that sends 3 variables to an external php script, it then adds them into an array and sends the array back, and i want it to output it in the javascript console, so that i can check that the variables are being passed back successfully, however when i run the script nothing appears in the console, only that

```
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost/blank/scripts/ajax/profile_password_submit.php".
```

Here is the ajax

```
$("#pro_content_password").submit(function() {

    var url = "scripts/ajax/profile_password_submit.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
    var js_array=new Array();
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#pro_content_password").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data){

                js_array=data;

                console.log(js_array);

             },
             dataType: 'json'
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

Here is the external php script

```
    session_start();
  include '../../connect.php';

  $user_id = "";
  $user_id = $_SESSION['userId'];
  echo $user_id;
 if(empty($_SESSION['userId'])){

     echo "user id session not set";
     exit;
  }


$old_password = $_POST['pro_content_password_old'];
$new_password = $_POST['pro_content_password_new'];
$new_password1 = $_POST['pro_content_password_verify'];


$password_array = array("old"=>$old_password,"new"=>$new_password, "new1"=>$new_password1);


echo json_encode($password_array);
```

Any ideas? Also i am using Google Chrome console

Comment: Do you just need to do console.log instead of document.write?

Comment: Are you sure, that everything works correctly?
Try to put "exit('ok');" as first row in your php file. Then open "Network tab" in Developers Tools and try to watch response of request. If there is your 'ok' then you can just try var_dump()... If not - let's see more.

Comment: document.write does nothing as well, and i have passed other variables correctly with the script, just not arrays

Comment: ok, i tested the `exit(ok)` and it showed correctly, so it tried `var_dump($password_array)` and it showed the array correctly in some preivew section in the network area, so does that mean there is a problem in the javascript section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final working version now, its a lot different to my original but it works a lot better

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function submit_profile_password(){
    //var results = document.getElementById("results");
    var result_error = document.getElementById("pro_content_error_password");
    var old_error = document.getElementById("pro_password_old_comment");
    var new_error = document.getElementById("pro_password_new_comment");
    var new1_error = document.getElementById("pro_password_new1_comment");

    var oldPass = document.getElementsByName("pro_content_password_old")[0].value;
    var newPass = document.getElementsByName("pro_content_password_new")[0].value;
    var new1Pass = document.getElementsByName("pro_content_password_verify")[0].value;
    var vars = "oldPass="+oldPass+"&newPass="+newPass+"&new1Pass="+new1Pass;

    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("POST", "scripts/ajax/profile_password_submit.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
            //results.innerHTML = "";

            for(var obj in data){
                if(obj == "old"){
                    old_error.innerHTML = "";
                    old_error.innerHTML = data[obj];

                }else if(obj == "new"){
                    new_error.innerHTML = "";
                    new_error.innerHTML = data[obj];

                }else if(obj == "new1"){
                    new1_error.innerHTML = "";
                    new1_error.innerHTML = data[obj];

                }else if(obj == "result"){
                    result_error.innerHTML = "";
                    result_error.innerHTML = data[obj];

                }

                //alert("Key = "+obj+"value = "+data[obj]+"");

            }
        }
    }
    hr.send(vars);
    //results.innerHTML = "requesting...";
    return false; 
}





</script>
```

Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not outputting a proper JSON object. I don't know for a fact, since you haven't shared what your PHP script is outputting, but I have a feeling that this line in that is what's causing your problem:

```
echo $user_id;
```

You're not just outputting a JSON encoded PHP array, you're also outputting the `$user_id` variable.

jQuery's ajax success callback only fires if it receives a properly formatted JSON object, which yours is not. It probably looks something more like this:

`1234{"old": "oldpass", "new": "newpass", "new1": "newpass1"}`

Comment: Hi, i commented out the echo of the user_id, but it still doesn't show in the array in the console, only in the network section of the developer tools in chrome

Answer (score 0):

You need JSON.stringify :

```
$("#pro_content_password").submit(function() {

    var url = "scripts/ajax/profile_password_submit.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
    var js_array=new Array();
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#pro_content_password").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data){

                js_array=JSON.stringify(data);

                console.log(js_array);

             },
             dataType: 'json'
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

Comment: it means that scripts/ajax/profile_password_submit.php isn't returning data. You can debug that in the Network tab, just click to expand the call and you should see data.

Comment: yeah i can see the correct array showing in the network tab when i var_dump the array in the php script, but what would be causing it to not display in the javascript?

Comment: Did you add header('Content-Type: application/json'); and outputed the data with : echo json_encode( $arr ); .. Note that the page shouldn't contain anything else, or it will broke JSON format

Comment: no i didn't add that in the header, and there is a lot of other code on the page as well like html, php etc...

Comment: Output should contain only the JSON string, no html tags etc.

Comment: what exactly do i have to add to the head of the page

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_php_example.htm Here you have an example, json header is not necessary for ajax call to work.

Comment: no need to stringify just to log to console...easier to inspect if you don't